# Check string in select statement using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here I need to check the string which is in the format '`a,c,e`'. This situation occurred when user select multiple option from check box and in the query I need to check it with the present column.

**Example**:

Given string:

```
'a,c,e'
```

Need to check the given string each word is present in the column `columnA` or not:

```
columnA    columnB
-------------------
a            1
b            2
c            3
d            4
e            5
f            6
g            7
h            8
```

If `a,c,e` present in the column `columnA` it should retrieve with the `columnB`:

**Expected Result**:

```
columnA   columnB
------------------
a            1
c            3
e            5
```

My try:

```
select columnA,columnB from 
test where columnA ='a' 
or columnA = 'c' 
or columnA = 'e'
```

I don't feel! this is the optimize way to do so. And this is also not good for the dynamic query where the string values become changes concurrently.

Comment: That query is fine. It it as optimal as it is going to get, if columnA has indices. Alternatively, it can be expressed as `where columnA IN ('a', 'c', 'e')`; but this will *not* make it "more optimized".. and I have no idea what "string value .. changes concurrently" is referring to.

Comment: The method will work if input is certain static a, c, e.. but if you are talking about dynamic input then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

```
DECLARE @COMMASEPSTR NVARCHAR(200), @SQL nvarchar(max), @STR  nvarchar(100) = 'a,b,c'
 SET @COMMASEPSTR= '''' + REPLACE(@STR,',',''',''') + ''''

SET @SQL = 'select columnA,columnB from 
test where columnA IN ( ' + @COMMASEPSTR + ')'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Tell me if I am wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the format of your dynamic input string or format of columnA but you can try this:

```
select columnA,columnB from 
test where CHARINDEX(columnA, 'a,c,e')>0
```

Comment: This method will never be able to use indices, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: According to question input string can vary. Means, it can be dynamic

Comment: True; I would still move the parsing of the string to an appropriate SQL statement to the application-layer. This does the advantage of not needing that (for laziness, if nothing else ;-)

Comment: Better to write a function to split the string into arrays.. unfortunately SQL Server doesn't have Split like C#

Answer (score 1):

You can use the IN syntax:

```
select columnA,columnB from 
test where columnA IN ('a','b','c')
```

Answer (score 0):

try to make ur life easier, put your input string before column in select statement.

```
declare @temp table
(
ColumnA NVARCHAR(MAX),
ColumnB NVARCHAR(MAX)
)


insert into @temp
select 'a','1'
union all
select 'b','2'
union all
select 'c','3'
union all
select 'd','4'
union all
select 'e','5'
union all
select 'f','6'
union all
select 'g','7'

DECLARE @input NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @input= 'a,d,c'

select * from @temp where @input like '%' + ColumnA +'%'
```